# How to sort excel table by column cell values with Java?

Tags: java

I am experiencing a problem with the order of an excel table column. Sample result of my program:

```
PAGE | NAME
 106 | 29100004-01
 108 | 36110001-01
 11  | 29100020-01
 110 | 24000017-01
 112 | 32430002-01
 114 | 3831000201A
 116 | 26150003-01
 118 | 52210001-01
 120 | 35100008-01
 122 | 29100009-01
 124 | 32400014-01
 126 | 32330005-01
 128 | 35100001-01
 13  | 26234201-03
 130 | 27514401-01
 133 | 27510002-01
```

I use the following source:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
// Create a blank sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("WORKPACK DATA");

// This data needs to be written (Object[])
Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();

String strPreviousPage ="";

for (int i = 0; i < pdDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    PDPage CurrentPage = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
    pdfStripper.extractRegions(CurrentPage);
    int currentRow = i + 1;
    Text = pdfStripper.getTextForRegion("KeyWordRegion");
    if (Text.toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase()))
    {
        TextCRI = pdfStripper.getTextForRegion("ExternalIdent");
        String str = TextCRI.replace("\r\n", "");
        String str2 = str.replace(" ", "");

        if (str2.equalsIgnoreCase(strPreviousPage))
        {       
            System.out.println("Keyword found on current page!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Keyword found on current page!");
            data.put(Integer.toString(currentRow), new Object[] {i + 1, str2 });
        }
        strPreviousPage = str2;
    } 
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Keyword NOT found on current page!");
    }       
}
pdDoc.close();

// Iterate over data and write to sheet
Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
int rownum = 0;
for (String key : keyset)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr)
    {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        if (obj instanceof String)
            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
        else if (obj instanceof Integer)
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
    }
}

try
{
    // Write the workbook in file system
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\INPUT\\STANIMIROV.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("C:\\INPUT\\STANIMIROV.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I sort the data in the table? I need the `PAGES` order to be 11, 13, 15, ... not 10, 101, 12, 125, 13, 131, ...

Comment: Instead of doing it like this, do it the Java way: create a class to hold each row, implement `Comparable`, and use `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Column Strings into Integers, e.g., `Integer.parseInt(value)`. What you are seeing is ordering based on ASCII values, not numeric values.